# What do you call an anomaly/signature detection algorithm in data science

Tags: anomaly-detection

If I have an algorithm for detecting a set of data points that indicate with a high level of certainty that some event has occured OR that behaviors outside of a set model are occuring.

What would you call the algorithm used to detect these anomalies?

And

Would calling it an "analytic" be incorrect?

Comment: I think it depends on how the method works. If you can not get more specific, I think [Anomaly Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) is a proper term. I would be careful with terms like "analytical", since it can give a missleading impression that a method is not approximate.

Comment: @André I was trying to avoid being specific on purpose, because the intent is to collect many different methods for detecting many different attacks in a programmatic manner. 

One specific example would be detecting a ICMP tunneling by observing unusual spikes in ICMP messages or unusually large ICMP packets.

Comment: if event is not acceptable event, u can call ur algo as abnormality detection also. There are many abnormality detection algorithms based on problem statement, It can be supervised/ unsupervised or combination of both. -https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2018/07/anomaly-detection-anomaly-detection-by.html

Comment: Analytic would be too generalized term for ur algo